# Do external touchscreens exist?

Tags: displays, touchscreen

For example, the touchscreens of the phones are quite transparent and I believe, it is probably not too hard to build touchscreens what we can attach to already existing touch-less displays. On this way, a non-touchscreen screen (monitor or laptop) could be made a touchscreen, with a zero or minimal worsening of the display.

I imagine, I could maybe buy such a thing and then attach to me laptop display (for example, by clamps).

It could get its power and communicate the touch events, for example, over usb.

Is it possible? Do such thing exist?

Comment: I hope it is needless to say: "buy a touchscreen laptop" is NAA.

Comment: I know the Raspberry Pi has that but they are not very common and those screens are also small

Comment: @lrsu85 Thanks, that helps a lot. Can you give some link or at least keywords for that? Maybe I will find the same for pc as well.

Comment: Oh after a quick "touchscreen" google I found this: https://www.coolblue.nl/en/monitors/touchscreen so they are more commen than I thought...

Comment: @Irsu85 Right, but it is still not what I want. What I want, that is only an additional glass layer what I myself can put to an already existing, non-touch display.

Comment: In that case I will just say buy a touchscreen laptop because then thats the only real option

Comment: @Irsu85 Right but that is not okay. It is not needed to happen on this way. If I buy a new glass for my phone, I have actually bought exactly what I need - except that it is small and lacks an USB connection. Why the same does not exist in monitor size, at least for the standard one (14", 17")? I think, yes it exists but it is not so well advertised.

Comment: You are right but that is the market right now. Manufacturers don't do that kinda upgradability

Comment: I know add-on touchscreen hardware was available for CRT monitors, and it seems like the same kind of product still does exist to some degree; a web search found, for example, https://www.touchwindow.com/c/ExternalAddOnTouch.html — not a recommendation as I have done no real research.

Comment: @KevinReid It is the case as a google keyword worths more than any answer :-) This time, the keywords are: "touchscreen overlay". Overlay means that there is no display behind it, it can be attached before an existing display. Thank you very much! My ebay searches for "usb touchscreen overlay" are pretty nice. Unfrtunately, they are much most costly as I have ever expected, but maybe...